# Protocol Changes from HTTP2 to SPDY for C# WEB API

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, http2, spdy

We have Angular + WEB API Application, Deployed on Azure. After deployment currently we can see SPDY protocol in CHROME (Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)) network Tab. But previously we were able to see HTTP2 protocol for Web API request. What steps we need to follow to get back HTTP2 request.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot and Chrome version number please? Chrome turned off SPDY support over two years ago: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html?m=1

Comment: @BarryPollard Updated in main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.

It looks like there's at least one bug (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704146) for cached resources which might explain your middle two requests - they are light grey to show the cached resources were used.

However I can also see the same thing happens to other requests to that site (or related sites) in both your example and some of my own testing.

In short these appears to be display bugs, rather than genuinely downloading over SPDY. As I mentioned in the comments Chrome has deprecated SPDY and no longer supports it so it cannot be SPDY.

You can also prove this in the following ways:

1. Open the request in a new tab and you will see it downloads either as `h2` or `http/2+quic/` which will show what should actually be used on the sites in question. And this is the step you need to "get back to HTTP2" in the short term.
2. Use the chrome://net-internals/#http2 and chrome://net-internals/#quic pages and you will see the requests WERE downloaded over h2 or quic. So it's definitely just reporting the incorrect protocol to the network tab.
3. Check your own logs, where you will again see they are requested over HTTP/2 (or QUIC if you support that).

HTTP/2 and QUIC were built on a lot of the SPDY code in Chrome and looks like it's still referenced in lots of places.

So basically you don't need to do anything, and should just ignore it. If you really feel strongly about it then raise a bug to the Chrome team, or comment or star the above bug so you see updates to it and when they fix it.